# Deserialize Avro Data from bytes

Tags: java, avro

I am trying to deserialize, i.e., get an object of class `org.apache.avro.generic.GenericRecord` from byte array Avro data. This data contains a header with the full schema.

So far, I have tried this:

```
public List<GenericRecord> deserializeGenericWithSchema(byte[] message) throws IOException {
    List<GenericRecord> listOfRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
    DataFileReader<GenericRecord> fileReader =
            new DataFileReader<>(new SeekableByteArrayInput(message), reader);

    GenericRecord record = null;

    while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
        listOfRecords.add(fileReader.next(record));
    }

    return listOfRecords;
}
```

But I am getting an error:

> java.io.IOException: Invalid int encoding at
>
> org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readInt(BinaryDecoder.java:145) at
>
> org.apache.avro.io.BinaryDecoder.readBytes(BinaryDecoder.java:282) at
>
> org.apache.avro.file.DataFileStream.initialize(DataFileStream.java:112)
>
> at org.apache.avro.file.DataFileReader.(DataFileReader.java:97)

However, if I write to disk the byte array `message` and change my function like:

```
public List<GenericRecord> deserializeGenericWithSchema(String fileName) throws IOException {
    byte[] file = new File(fileName);
    List<GenericRecord> listOfRecords = new ArrayList<>();
    DatumReader<GenericRecord> reader = new GenericDatumReader<>();
    DataFileReader<GenericRecord> fileReader =
            new DataFileReader<>(file, reader);

    GenericRecord record = null;

    while (fileReader.hasNext()) {
        listOfRecords.add(fileReader.next(record));
    }

    return listOfRecords;
}
```

It works flawlessly. I really don't want to write to disk every avro message I get because this is intended to work in a real time basis.

What am I doing wrong in my first approach?

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any follow up on the issue? My assumption is encoding issue. Where the byte[] came from? Is it the exact byte[] you are writing to the disk? Maybe the explanation is on both File writer and reader default encoding settings.